# Replace Single value Dropdown with text and call a function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am populating a dropdown with dynamic values and on change of that dropdown I am calling another function. Now if only one value comes for the dropdown I want to show it as a static text and at the the same time call the function. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please post some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide your code I will be able to give a more customized answer, but here goes:

1:
When you fetch the dynamic data for the dropdownlist, use a count based if / else

1.1 : If the number of values fetched is 1 (one) then
1.1.1 : Hide the dropdownlist and inset a literal in it's position
1.1.2 : Call the second function

1.2 : If more than 1 (one) values is feteched then
1.2.1 : Populate the dropdownlist with the values
1.2.2 : Bind the .change() function to the dropdownlist

Sample Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax(
        url: 'asdasd',
        type: POST,
        success: function(data){
            var p = [];
            $.each(data, function(key, val){
                p.push(key, val);
            });
            if(p.length > 1)
            {
                // bind values to dropdownlist and add handle for change event
            }
            else
            {
                $(".dropdownlist").html(p[0][1]);
                fetchSecondaryData();
            }
        }
    );
```

});

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly you're filling a select dynamically and binding a function to its change event, and if the value is 'MyValue' run a special code. you can add this change to your function something like:

```
$('select.yourSelectClass).change(function(){
if $(this).val() == 'YourValue')
{
// Do whatever you have to do when this value is selected
}
// General processing for the change event
});
```

Comment: thnx for your answer but here I am not concerned with the values that are coming, my concern is the no of option values.If the no of option value is 1 then I want to change the dropdown to text and at the same time call a function.

Comment: I don't understand no of Option can you get it from the option value? I suggest to make 2 controls like <span>Your Text</span> and your dropdown then according to option selected hide & show yours controls.